# why for loop test check only first item in dictionary

Tags: python

this user check only first item in dectionary

```
def update_details():# here the user choose which feild he want to update
    input_details = input("please select which field you want to change: ")
    for item in store_group_details: #check if feild exist in decionary 
        if item == input_details:  # removed ['type']
            update_all_feature(input_details) # send input_details to update_all_feature() function
            break
        else: 
            print ("your input dose not exist? ")
            update_details()
```

following dictionry i want to eterate over it

```
'app_group2': ['slack', ' Discord', 'zoom', 'vs code'], 'Date': '2222-02-12'}
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the items stored in `app_group2`?

Comment: no i want iterate over store_group_details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you have the wrong `if/else` statement. When the first item is not in the list you **`break` from the loop and run the whole function again without checking other items**.

You have to put `else` one indentation before (to make `for/else` statement):

```py
for item in store_group_details:
    if item == input_details:
        update_all_feature(input_details)
        break
else:
    print("your input does not exist? ")
    update_details()
```